# What index should be created in mysql when where condition is made up of 'AND' and 'OR' combination?

Tags: mysql, indexing

My mysql query is like below, I need to create index to boost up result fetching.

```
   SELECT * FROM  tbl_name 
    WHERE seasonid = 1 AND status = 'N' 
AND month = 10 AND (team_a = 'India' OR team_b = 'India');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use **seasonid** as index

Comment: use a composite Index of all field in Where. the order of the fields are important. Use the Field with the smalest result at first, and so on. You can see the using of the INDEX or not using with an EXPLAIN before your Query

Comment: The usefulness of an index depends on its cardinality. A composite index on (seasonid,status,month) seems like an obvious contender, but it may be useful to include one or other of the team columns too.

Answer (score 0):

`(a = 1 OR a = 3)` is turned into `a IN (1,3)`, which is sometimes optimizable.  However, you don't have that case.  Therefore, the expressions on either side of `OR` are useless for indexing.

```
INDEX(seasonid,status,month)
```

with the 3 fields in any order is the 'best' index for that query.

See also my [*index cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).